# Error when installing the keystone.js generator

Tags: node.js, npm, keystonejs

Every time I try to install generator-keystone, I get this error:

```
~ $sudo npm install -g generator-keystone
npm WARN deprecated CSSselect@0.4.1: the module is now available as 'css-select'
npm WARN deprecated CSSwhat@0.4.7: the module is now available as 'css-what'
npm ERR! Darwin 15.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "generator-keystone"
npm ERR! node v4.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.10

npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

I have previously installed generator-keystone with no problems, so I am at a loss as to what is causing this.